# Angular controller functions are both constructors and a decorators?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

If one writes a `controller as ctrl` for the following code:

```
function Controller($scope) {
  $scope.abc = "123";
}

angularApp.controller("controller", Controller);
```

Does the pseudo code below accurately describe how `$scope` differs from `controller`?

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
controller = new Controller($scope);
$scope.ctrl = controller;
```

**My question is:**

- Is the above pseudo code an accurate mental model of how a scope differs from a controller object?
- Is `function Controller(){}` both a constructor function (for controller objects) and a decorator (for scope objects) at the same time?

Comment: The controller doesn't decorate a scope, it just gets added to it as a property. A decorator as I understand it is a wrapper for a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Scope is dumb- for many reasons. That's why they're fading it out and it won't exist in angular 2. It's recommended that you don't use scope ever but only for `watch`, `eval`, and events.